# Issue with JavaScript hasOwnProperty in Selectize createFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm trying to figure out the workings of a neat jQuery based library called [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/).

On the demos-page they have an example of the "createFilter" function, which I want to use to check whether the user input already exist, and if not, create the item.

The example from selectize.js (meant for e-mail):

```
createFilter: function(input) {
    var match, regex;

    // email@address.com
    regex = new RegExp('^' + REGEX_EMAIL + '$', 'i');
    match = input.match(regex);
    if (match) return !this.options.hasOwnProperty(match[0]);

    // name <email@address.com>
    regex = new RegExp('^([^<]*)\<' + REGEX_EMAIL + '\>$', 'i');
    match = input.match(regex);
    if (match) return !this.options.hasOwnProperty(match[2]);

    return false;
},
```

My own take on making a filter to only allow letters, and check if it's already in the list:

```
createFilter: function (input) {

    var match, regex;
    regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ][a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ ]*[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]$', 'i');
    match = input.match(regex);

    if (match) return !this.options.hasOwnProperty(match[0]);

    return false;
},
```

For some reason it always returns `true` thus allowing the user to add a new item, even though it already exists, after hours of testing, I'm convinced it has something to do with this.options.hasOwnProperty - but I'm at a dead end figuring out what and why, any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you're using `.hasOwnProperty` correctly. It's only used to differentiate prototype properties and methods from the object's own properties/methods. Try `this.options[match[0]]===undefined` instead. If this helps, let me know so that I can add it as an answer.

Comment: @JonathanGray - That doesn't sound right. It's perfectly OK to use `.hasOwnProperty()` to test if a property exists, as illustrated in the selectize example code. It isn't limited to use only in distinguishing between prototype properties and object properties. If your suggested code works, then `.hasOwnProperty()` should too.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - that's exactly what I thought! But I'm simply not able to figure out what the reason for it not working is... I was hoping someone would be able to see what happens..

Comment: @Michael - Do you have any idea? Maybe I am getting something completely wrong here... I just tried testing with a very vanilla `createFilter`: `!this.options.hasOwnProperty(input);` - this also always returns true??

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to get the createFilter to work as well, and looked into the source, but things seems setup properly but there is a clearly a bug in there somewhere. For now my solution was the use of the actual create method. If you dig a bit in the source (alluded to by the documentation on the create option) you will notice that prior to item creation it will check if your value of create is a function:

```
var setup = (typeof self.settings.create === 'function') ? this.settings.create : function(input) {
  var data = {};
  data[self.settings.labelField] = input;
  data[self.settings.valueField] = input;
  return data;
};
```

By passing in a creation function that only returns a value for data when a certain condition is passed, else it returns {}, you can effectively do exactly what you wanted to do in the createFilter function.

```
$('#foo').selectize({
    create: function(input){
      var self = this;
      var data = {};
      // IF SOME CONDITION MET
      if (bar) {
        data[self.settings.labelField] = input;
        data[self.settings.valueField] = input;
      }          
      return data;
    },
 });
```

If data is returned as {}, the item is not created and the user can continue to modify it as needed (or be informed that there selection was invalid).